# Problemas autentificación login django

Tags: python, django, django-views

Hola mi nombre es Alan y he estado teniendo problemas a la hora de desarrollar un login, no sé que pasa pero a la hora de ingresar al sitio no lo valida y puedes poner lo que sea y te da acceso, sabes que estoy haciendo mal?? muchas gracias y soy nuevo en esto.

```
def logUser(request):
    logUs=loginUsers()

    if request.method =="POST":
        logUs=loginUsers(data=request.POST)
        if logUs.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get('name','')
            code = request.POST.get('code','') 
            na=Client.objects.filter(name='name',code='code')
            na.filter()

            return redirect(reverse('support'))  


    return render(request, 'support/login.html', {'form':logUs})
```

Comment: Hola Alan, no veo ningún login, pues no veo que autentiques al usuario. Y según tu vista sea cual sean los valores de los campos del formulario (mientras sean valores validos según los campos) podrán ingresar al "sitio".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no estas haciendo ningun login o bueno yo no lo veo primero importamos la funcion la cual hara el login

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
```

despues de eso tenemos que tomar los valores que se envian en el metodo post e ingresar esos valores en la funcion.

```
def log_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

una vez que hagas eso los datos son guardados de lo contrario pues no, una vez hecho eso tendras que redirijir a la vista que desees

```
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('tu direccion de la pagina')
```

si quieres saber mas puedes leer la documentacion https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/